# How to resize disk partition CentOS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, centos

I have parallels mac os desktop and I run centOS. My problem is that I can't make this   Disk `/dev/mapper/vg_host-lv_root` bigger.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 549.8 GB, 549755813888 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 66837 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00076df4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       66838   536357888   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_host-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_host-lv_swap: 4227 MB, 4227858432 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 514 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_host-lv_home: 10.3 GB, 10276044800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1249 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Why you cannot make it bigger? What did you try?

Comment: I find a solution :) http://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/linux-server-c37687/administration-help-c37694/increase-the-size-of-the-logical-volume-a756168.html

Comment: Great! After the time limit for self-reply passes could you please write essential parts of the article and the link as a reply?